# Cannot find D3.js memory leak

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I'm a bit stuck, I created a D3 application that retrieves a bunch of sensor information from a database.  I've made it so that it transitions and operates on a 30 second loop to update the information.  It parses a Javascript Object and plots a line for each sensor on a graph.  Everything seems to go well, but a couple of hours in the app will grind to a halt and stop updating.  Then it complains about a script not responding.  Here's the JS for the plot:

```
var thresholdTemp = 72;
var minutes = 5;
var transInterval;

//Main function to create a graph plot
function plot(date1, date2, interval) {
        var data;
        //If we define a date search parameter then we don't want to have it load          interactive
        if (date1 == undefined && date2==undefined) {
                data = loadMinutesJSON(minutes);
        } else {
                data = searchJSON(date1, date2, interval);

        }
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 60, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right ,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        //Re-order the data to be more usable  by the rest of the script
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
        //Convert the JSON to be better usable by D3
        data = convertJSON(data);
        //Nest the data so that it's grouped by serial number
        data = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.serial; }).entries(data);

        //Set the X domain to exist within the date and times given
        var x = d3.time.scale().domain([getMinDate(data), getMaxDate(data)]).range([0, (width)]);


        //Y Axis scale set to start at 45 degrees and go up to 30 degrees over highest temp
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([
                45,
                getMaxTemp(data) + 10
             ])
            .range([height, 0]);


        //Set up the line colors based on serial number, this generates a color based on an ordinal value
        var color = d3.scale.category20()
                        .domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key)  { return key === 'serial';}));

        //Define where the X axis is    
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d %H:%M:%S"));

        //Define where the Y axis is
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        //When called creates a line with the given datapoints
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        y(function(d) { return y(d.reading); });

        //An extra line to define a maximum temperature threshold
        var threshold = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date);})
            .y(function(d) { return y(thresholdTemp); });

        //Append the SVG to the HTML element
        var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
            .attr("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right))
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Define the clipping boundaries
        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", (width + margin.left +  margin.right))
            .attr("height", height +  margin.top + margin.bottom);

        //Add the X axis        
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform" , function (d) {return "rotate(-35)"});

        //Add the Y axis and a label denoting it as temperature in F    
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Temperature (F)");

        //Create the lines based on serial number
        var serial = svg.selectAll(".serial")
                .data(data, function(d) { return d.key;})
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "serial");
        //Add the extra line for a threshold and align it with the current time
        var threshElement = svg.selectAll(".thresh")
                .data(data, function(d) { return d.key;})
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", ".thresh");
        //Add the path to draw lines and clipping so they stay within bounds    
        var path = serial.append("path")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function (d) {return line(d.values);})
                .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.key);});

        //Custom path to add a line showing the temperature threshold
        var threshpath = threshElement.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function(d) { return threshold(d.values);})
                .style("stroke", "red");

        //Add a label to the end of the threshold line denoting it as the threshold
        threshElement.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(getMaxDate(data)) + "," + y(thresholdTemp + .5) + ")")
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text("Threshold");
        //Add the legend
        plotLegend(data);

        //Load in the new data and add it to the SVG

        function transition() {
                var newdata = loadMinutesJSON(minutes);
                newdata = convertJSON(newdata);
                console.log(newdata.length);
                newdata = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.serial; }).entries(newdata);
                if (data[0]["values"][0]["date"].toString() === newdata[0]["values"][0]["date"].toString()) { console.log("No New Data");return;}

                //Merge the new data with the old and remove duplicates
                data = merge(data,newdata);
                //Chop off the preceding data that is no longer needed or visible
                data = reduce(data, minutes);

                x.domain([getMinDate(data), getMaxDate(data)]);
                y.domain([45, getMaxTemp(data) + 10]);
                d3.select(".x.axis")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500).call(xAxis)
                        .selectAll("text")
                        .style("text-anchor", "end")
                        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                        .attr("dy", ".15em")
                        .attr("transform" , function (d) {return "rotate(-35)"});

                d3.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(500).call(yAxis);
                var serial2 = svg.selectAll(".serial")
                        .data(data, function(d) { return d.key;});
                        serial2.enter().append("g").attr("class", "line");

                var threshold2 = svg.selectAll(".thresh")
                        .data(data, function(d) { return d.key;});
                        threshold2.enter().append("g").attr("class", "line");

                threshpath
                        .attr("d", function(d) {return threshold(d.values);})
                .attr("transform", null)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .ease("linear");

                threshElement.selectAll("text")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(getMaxDate(data)) + "," + y(thresholdTemp + .5 ) + ")")
                        .attr("x", 3)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .ease("linear");

                path
                        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values);})
                        .attr("transform", null)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .ease("linear");
                        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")");
                console.log(svg);
                serial2.exit().remove();
                threshold2.exit().remove();

                //Remove the old, unused data
                //data = reduce(data, minutes);
        }

        if(date1 == undefined && date2 == undefined) {
                //Set the transition loop to run every 30 seconds
                transInterval = setInterval(transition,30000);

        }
}
```

Here's an example of the data structure:

```
[{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:19.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:50.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:20.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:50.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:20.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:50.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:20.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:50.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:20.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"2D0008017075F210","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:50.000Z","reading":76.1,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:19.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:50.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:20.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:50.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:20.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:50.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:20.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:50.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:20.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"1D00080170496D10","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:50.000Z","reading":73.4,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:19.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:35:50.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:20.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:36:50.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:20.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:37:50.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:20.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:38:50.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:20.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null},{"serial":"380008017037ED10","date":"2013-08-23T14:39:50.000Z","reading":74.3,"elevation":null,"room":null,"system":null}]
```

Comment: Leaks can't readily be seen in code. I suggest you run a timeline recording in Chrome and investigate the memory use, as well as what runs when.

Comment: Read this article to learn how to detect memory leaks: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#three-snapshot-technique.

Comment: I see that you accepted an answer but I'm curious what part of the code turned out to be leaking? Was it specific to certain browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch your memory usage with the debugger. Remove code. Check if memory leak still occurs. Rinse and repeat.

Also, as a suggestion, don't use `setInterval()`. Use `setTimeout()` recursively instead.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Nope, just straight up debugging grinding.

Comment: I will say that I prefer setInterval() over setTimeout in this particular case.  One, it only runs every 30 seconds so the difference is pretty much negligible.  The other reason is that setInterval() is easier to cancel so I can feed in new datasets whenever I want to(which is a thing that I want to do).

Comment: The difference in 1 iteration is negligible...but if you keep your browser open long enough, it absolutely does. Just google "setInterval ajax desync" problems and you'll see. Also, `setTimeout()` is just as easy to cancel...`var a = setTimeout(); clearTimeout(a);`